# Using DI in ASP.Net Core IPasswordValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-identity

I'm implementing a custom password validator in ASP.Net Core to check passwords against the have I been pwend API.
All the logic for checking against the have I been pwned API is in a separate class that get's injected into the custom password validator.

A little simplified things look like this:

##### Have I been pwned service

```
public class HaveIBeenPwnedService : IDisposable
{
    private const string _baseUri = "https://api.pwnedpasswords.com";
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly SHA1 _sha1;

    public HaveIBeenPwnedService()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _sha1 = SHA1.Create();
    } 

    public async Task<bool> IsPasswordCompromised(string password)
    {
        ....
    }

    ....
}
```

##### Custom password Validator

```
public class CustomPasswordValidator<TUser> : IPasswordValidator<TUser>
where TUser : IdentityUser
{
    private readonly HaveIBeenPwnedService _haveIBeenPwnedService;

    public CustomPasswordValidator(HaveIBeenPwnedService haveIBeenPwnedService)
    {
        _haveIBeenPwnedService = haveIBeenPwnedService;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user, string password)
    {
        if (await _haveIBeenPwnedService.IsPasswordCompromised(password))
            {
                return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
                {
                    ....
                });
            }

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

##### Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            ....
        })
        .AddPasswordValidator<CustomPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>>()
```

I was a little surprised when I realized, that the HaveIBeenPwnedService Class is created on every single Request. I was more expecting it to be created only where the CustomPasswordValidator is used (password reset, change password, ...).
But I guess that's because the PasswordValidator itself get's injected somewhere in ASP Identity.

**Now my question:**

Since the HaveIBeenPwnedService is instantiating the HttpClient a SHA1 in the constructor and also disposing it and all that is done in every request (but only really used in maybe 1%) is it a bad idea to inject the HaveIBeenPwnedService into the CustomPasswordValidator?
Would it be more efficient to just instantiate the HaveIBeenPwnedService in ValidateAsync and remove all the contructors? Am I overthinking it?
What do you think?

Comment: Over thinking it. The service should be registered as a singleton so it is created once. also consider refactoring your code to use abstractions along with the HttpClientFactory instead of creating the client every time as that can cause socket exhaustion.

Comment: @Nkosi `HaveIBeenPwnedService` might be registered as [typed http client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-clients). Also, unless you're keeping state inside `HaveIBeenPwnedService`, or creating a lot of instances, leaving it with transient lifetime is ok.

Comment: @abdusco type httpclient still allows abstracted clients `AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation>(...`

Comment: True, I was commenting on the need for `HttpClientFactory`

Comment: @abdusco I was referring to the framework not necessarily the class/interface itself

Comment: @Nkosi thanks, I was not aware of the HttpClientFacotry. When implementing the `HaveIBeenPwnedService` as a singleton with HttpClientFacotry injected, would you create the HttpClient in the `IsPasswordCompromised` function or the constructor and reuse it? Will a HttpClient created in the function ever be disposed during the application lifetime?

Comment: @McGu Check out this article for more details about the different ways HttpClientFactory can be used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests